# Regex to Split String on Even Number of Preceding Characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to develop a regex that will split a string on a single quote only if the single quote is preceded by zero question marks, or an even number of question marks. For example, the following string:

```
ABC??'DEF?'GHI'JKL????'MNO'
```

would result in:

```
ABC??
DEF?'GHI
JKL????
MNO
```

I've tried using this negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\?\?)*\'
```

But that results in:

```
ABC??
DEF?
GHI
JKL????
MNO
```

I've also tried the following

```
(?<!(\?\?)*)\'  results in runtime error
(?:\?\?)*\'
(?!\?\?)+\'
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quantifiers and lookaround don't really like each other. I believe Java only lets you use ? and {} in lookaround, while many languages don't even allow that.

Comment: I doubt a single regex can do this.  Is there a reason you can’t write a few lines of code to accomplish this, rather than a single `split` call?

Comment: @tsleyson Only for lookbehinds, for lookaheads you can use `*`

Comment: @dognose I had forgotten that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't handy to use the split method in this kind situations. A workaround consists to describe all that isn't the delimiter and to use the `find` method:

```
[^?']+(?:\?.[^?']*)*|(?:\?.[^?']*)+
```

[demo](http://fiddle.re/cte0un)

pattern details:

```
[^?']*     # zero or more characters that aren't a `?` or a `'`
(?:        # open a non-capturing group
    \? .   # a question mark followed by a character (that can be a `?` or a `'`)
    [^?']* # 
)*         # close the non-capturing group and repeat it zero or more times
```

`[^?']*(?:\?.[^?']*)*` describes all that isn't the delimiter including the empty string. To avoid empty matches, I use 2 branches of an alternation: `[^?']+(?:\?.[^?']*)*` and `(?:\?.[^?']*)+` to ensure there's at least one character.

*(If you want to allow the empty string at the start of the string, add `|^` at the end of the pattern)*

---

You can also use the split method but the pattern to do it isn't efficient since it needs to look backward for each position *(and is limited since the lookbehind in java allows only limited quantifiers)*:

```
(?<=(?<!\?)(?:\?\?){0,100})'
```

or perhaps more efficient like this:

```
'(?<=(?<!\?)(?:\?\?){0,100}')
```

Comment: Casimir, that works as you suggested ... using find().   Can you explain the regex?

Comment: @ShawnGeraghty: it isn't complicated, I will add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried positive lookbehind

(?<=.')

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4GwgtI/1)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do it:

```
[A-Z]+(\?\?)*'
```

Comment: Now it matches somewhat as expected, but still including `[A-Z]+` in the pattern would remove them upon split, which is not desired. Spliting should happen on `'` Only, so there is no way without lookarounds, cause they are non-consuming.

Comment: @dognose, that is correct.  Since I need the ? to remain, then I have to use lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you **only** need to handle a single question mark, not three, five, etc., you could use this:

```
(?<![^\?]\?)'
```

You could expand on this concept to match other specific odd numbers of question marks.  For example, this will properly not split on a quote preceded by one, three, or five question marks:

```
(?<![^\?]\?|[^\?]\?{3}|[^\?]\?{5})'
```

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/6Htf7E/1). Lookbehinds must be fixed-width, but some engines allow an OR of the entire lookbehind.  Others do not, and would require it be written as three separate lookbehinds:

```
(?<![^\?]\?)(?<![^\?]\?{3})(?<![^\?]\?{5})'
```

Obviously this is getting a bit messy, though.  And it can't handle an arbitrary odd number of ?.